URL rewrite help neded
Disclaimer: I'm a semi-skilled novice, I'd rather ask a pro for help than make it worse by guessing. My site is running a vBulletin Forum and nothing else. I upgraded and moved the website and now need help with a Google-friendly URL rewrite.

The original URLs were https://www.mywebsite.com/forums/... (forums is plural)

The "forum" in the new URLs is singular like https://www.mywebsite.com/forum/... there are also some changes after the /forum/ but I'm not sure if they matter since the target of the rewrite doesn't need them but the topic ID embedded in the URLs is what's needed


Any inbounds to the current URL format https://www.mywebsitet.com/forum/...  with the singular "forum" are good and don't need a rewrite
Here are two examples of old URLs that need rewrites"

https://www.mywebsite.com/forums/canon/176449-canon-ir-adv-dx-c5850-e355-003-error.html needs to be rewritten with a google friendly redirect to https://www.mywebsite.com/showthread.php?t=176449 the vbulletin system will then find/load the correct/current page.

Here's another http://www.mywebsite.com/forums/kyocera-mita-copystar/71926-fs-3900-dn-printer.html needs to be rewritten to https://www.mywebsitte.com/showthread.php?t=71926



You certainly want to redirect those old URLs (using "forums") to the new pretty URLs (using "forum") by means of an external 301 redirection. Then your normal internal rewriting rules can get applied to translate into your sites logic using HTTP GET parameters.
